# Is there a better way to access deeply nested JSON-like objects in Python?

Tags: python, json

I often have to deal with accessing deeply nested JSON responses. One way to access an element could be something like this:

```
json_['foo'][0][1]['bar'][3]
```

But that's obviously not at all safe. One solution is to use the `get` method of Python `dict` and pass `{}` as the default argument.

```
json_.get('foo', {})[0][1]['bar'][3]
```

But that again can raise an IndexError exception which leaves me with a length check for every list element access.

```
target = json_.get('foo', {})
if not target:
   return
target = target[0]
if len(target) < 2:
   return
target = target[1].get('bar', {})
if len(target) < 4:
   return
target = target[3]   #Finally...
```

And that's not at all pretty. So, is there a better solution for this?

Comment: If returning `None` is an option, why not `try: json_['foo'][0][1]['bar'][3]; except KeyError, IndexError: pass`?

Answer (score 6):

Just wrap the entire thing in `try/except`:

```
try:
    return json_['foo'][0][1]['bar'][3]
except IndexError, KeyError:
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answer, if you want to just ignore the exceptions you could use:

```
# Wrap this in a function
try:
    return json_['foo'][0][1]['bar'][3]
except (KeyError, IndexError):
    pass
```

Addtionally, another way is to suppress exceptions is with [`contextlib.suppress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress):

```
from contextlib import suppress

# Wrap this in a function
with suppress(KeyError, IndexError):
    return json_['foo'][0][1]['bar'][3]
```